# pushing and unshifting in one line doesn't work. what am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript

I'm getting an array of ints from an API denoting days.

```
[0, 7, 30, 356]
```

I wrote a small function that appends the `moment`-generated end-date (calculating days from now) but that's not important. The important part is that the second line of my ternary.

On `0`, I don't want to calculate the end-date, but just "no limit" as label and that entry as the last in the array

wanted result:

```
[{
  code: 7
  label: 'one week'
},
{
  code: 30,
  label: 'one month'
},
{
  code: 356,
  label: 'one year'
},
{
  code: 0,
  label: 'no limit
}]
```

I wanted to get real fancy and was already kind of proud about the elegant one-liner, but it just doesn't seem to work. It doesn't remove the first entry. entering it in devtools by itself returns the object literal though, so that part seems to be correct.

```
for (let i = 0, x = lengths.length; i < x; i++) {
  lengths[i]
    ? lengths[i] = //transform the entry here
    : lengths.push(lengths.shift() && {code: lengths[i], label: 'No limit'})
}
return lengths
```

Can anyone point out what exactly I am did wrong? I want to understand

## clarification:

I want to remove 0 from the first array position, transform and add it to the last postition at the same time

## edit

thanks to an answer here, i noticed that i used `unshift` instead of `shift`to remove the first element.. which of course didn't work

Comment: do you have some data of `lengths`? and the wanted result?

Comment: because i have it at the first and last position then. it's supposed to be a list with 7 days, 30 days, etc. and then finally "no limit"

Comment: do you have always zero at index zero?

Comment: if it is in the array, it is at zero, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some ugly code you can do something like this, i am using `,` operator to `shift()` and adjust the variables due to changes index because of mutation

```js
let lengths = [0, 30, 60, 90]

for (let i = 0, x = lengths.length; i < x; i++) {
  lengths[i]
    ? lengths[i] = {code: lengths[i], label: "dummy"}
    : (lengths.push({code: lengths[i], label: 'No limit'}), lengths.shift(), i--, x--)
}
 
console.log(lengths)
```

---

Close to your original code,

1. `!` need before shift as the return value of shift is `0` ( in our case ) so to make `&&` operator return object we need to make it truthy value
2. Need to adjust indexes else we miss out elements

```js
let lengths = [0, 30, 60, 90]

for (let i = 0, x = lengths.length; i < x; i++) {
  lengths[i]
    ? lengths[i] = {code: lengths[i], label: "dummy"}
    : (lengths.push(!lengths.shift() && {code: 0, label: 'No limit'}), i-- ,x--)
}
 
console.log(lengths)
```

P.S:- 1st point can be avoided by using `||` operator as nicely pointed out in nina's answer

Comment: oh wow i just noticed that i used UNshift, when i should have used SHIFT to remove the first one.....

Comment: this solution indeed works! i still don't understand why `lengths.push(lengths.shift() && {code: lengths[i], label: 'No limit'})` does not though. shouldn't this do the exact same thing? remove first, then add at the end? can you explain that please?

Comment: @devman when you shift it changes the index of all the values in array, so now your `{ code : lengths[i]...` will have wrong value and since the indexes are adjusted you will miss out elements in looping as well as you increase counter by 1 every time irrespective of mutating array or not

Comment: it was far less complicated... see Nina Scholz's answer. i just assumed shift would return the length of the array :D got it now. thank you very much. didn't consider that counter though, thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: @devman see the second version of the answer, it is closer to your code

Answer (score 2):

`lengths.unshift()` returns `value`, so it adding same value, not the  `{code: lengths[i], label: 'No limit'}`

**You can use splice:**

```
lengths.splice(lengths.length-1, 1, {code: lengths[i], label: 'No limit'})
```

Here `remove` 1, an element at `position lengths.length-1` and add `object`.

Comment: that adds it instead of the first one. i want to have it as the LAST element

Comment: than use last one

Comment: i repeat: i want to REMOVE the FIRST element, then ADD it back to the array as LAST element. are you sure this is what splice does?

Comment: However now you know the problem, you can twick the solution,My modtive to highlight the issue you have facing and suggest something work for u.

Answer (score 1):

You need a [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR) instead of a [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND), because `shift` returns zero and this is falsy. The following part in never evaluated this zero is pushed.

```
lengths.push(lengths.shift() || { code: lengths[i], label: 'No limit' })
//                           ^^
```

---

You could iterate from the end and shift at the end where item is left.

```js
var lengths = [0, 7, 30, 356],
    i = lengths.length;

while (i--) {
    if (lengths[i]) lengths[i] = { code: lengths[i], label: '...' };
    else {
        lengths.shift();
        lengths.push({ code: 0, label: 'no limit' });
    }
}

console.log(lengths);
```

A short approach is to shift and push before you change the values.

```js
var lengths = [0, 7, 30, 356];

lengths.push(lengths.shift());

console.log(lengths);
```

Comment: i still don't understand why it doesn't work on the same line. you're basically doing nothing else (and it WORKS when i do it on separate lines). what i'm trying to really understand is, why the `&&` construction fails

Comment: oh god WOW, that's it. thank you. now i understand. because i used `unshift` initially, i read that documentation, and `unshift` returns the length of the array, so i really had no idea why this kept failing. if `shift` returns the element, it all makes sense. now i got it. thank you very much :)